# Parsing method names out of javap with ruby

Tags: java, ruby, regex, parsing, methods

So currently im writing a ruby script to parse out method names from the list given to me after I run javap on a .class file. I have a feeling a regex (regular expression) is the only way to accomplish this but I wanted the community input before I attempted this.

So for instance the following methods are given to me by javap:

```
public String foo()
public int bar()
```

I would only want the foo and bar from that list, how would I go about extracting those only? Is regex the best way?

Answer (score 1):

I think a [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) with a positive look-ahead (for the opening parenthesis) should do the trick:

```
method_names = s.scan(/\w+(?=\s*\()/)
```

For example:

```
>> "public String foo()\npublic int bar(int)".scan(/\w+(?=\s*\()/)
=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

This assumes Ruby 1.9 and that Java method names will only contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and "_". Replacing the `\w` something broader (such as [`\p{Word}`](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt)) would allow for methods with names like `µü` and such.

Comment: Ok, I like this more than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
 /[\w ]+ (.*)\(.*\)/
```

This would match any 1 or more word character (a-z, A-Z, numbers and _) as well as a spaces, followed by a space and a word that's followed by whatever (`.*`) in parenthesis. The method name itself will be in the first capture group (`$1`).

http://www.rubular.com/r/5wKuYf4p1S

Comment: Actually "\w" will match more than [a-zA-Z_]

Comment: No problem what I've tried to point out is that ruby "\w" will match not only [a-zA-Z0-9_], but also characters like ▼áéíóú...

Comment: @Eder: Not in 1.9 it doesn't, `"µ".match(/\w/)` returns `nil`. If you want a non-ASCII version of `\w` you'd use `\p{Word}` instead.

Comment: @muistooshort, Nice, I didn't know about it. I just stayed at older version of ruby.